Has the notion of a unipotent group scheme been studied?
The concept of a unipotent algebraic group over a field has been extensively studied and is fundamental in algebraic geometry. However, has the notion of a unipotent group scheme over a general base scheme been studied? Both Demazure-Gabriel and SGA3 appear to only consider the case of a base field.
I am even uncertain about the definition of these objects. For a $\mathbb{Q}$-scheme $S$, I believe that a unipotent $S$-group scheme should be a (finitely presented?) group scheme over $S$ admitting a normal series with $\mathbb{G}_a$-factors. However, I am unsure about the definition for more general bases.

I think that the definition involving composition factors is not what you want (although of course you can study it—but note that, even over a field, it is only the right definition for smooth, connected group schemes).   I suspect that the proper definition should be that these are linear groups (i.e., admitting a faithful representation) for which every representation admits a non-$0$ fixed vector.

In char $p$, a cyclic group of order $p$ defines a (reduced, smooth, non-connected) unipotent group scheme.

One approach is described in Definition 5.9 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.15041.

Searching for "unipotent group scheme" came up with https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~idolga/izve74.pdf, which, together with the works it cites, contains lots of interesting material.

Dear @anon, this is very close to what I wanted. If you are willing to write this as an answer, I would happily accept it
